# ComboBox that shows a tree in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, combobox, treeview, dojo

I want to write a ComboBox which lets the user type in a query and at the same time lets him select a value from a tree. I have tried writing a tree-select but if I change the code to inherit from `dijit.form.ComboBox` instead of a `dijit.form.Select`, the code breaks.

Here is what I had tree for tree select:

```
dojo.declare('TreeSelect',dijit.form.Select,{
    constructor: function(widgetArgs){
        this.tree = widgetArgs.tree || new FC_Tree();
        this.initTree = widgetArgs.initTree;
        if(dojo.isFunction(this.initTree))
            this.initTree();
    },
    postCreate: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.option = {label: '', value: 'NoValue'};
        this.tree.option = this.option;
        this.addOption(this.option);

        dojo.connect(this.tree,'onClick',this,'closeDropDown');

        dojo.connect(this.tree,'itemSelected',this,'selectOption');
    },
    selectOption: function(opt){
        this.option.label = opt.label || opt;
        this.option.value = opt.value || opt;
        this.option.id = opt.id || opt;
        this.set('value',this.option);                      
    },
    _getMenuItemForOption: function (option){
        return this.tree;
    },
    openDropDown: function(){
        this.tree.refresh();
        this.inherited(arguments);
    },
    clear: function(){
        this.tree.clear();
        this.tree.option.value = '';
        this.tree.option.label = '';
        this.tree.option.id = '';
        this.set('value',this.tree.option);
    },

    initializeTree: function(treeData) {
        // Init the tree only if needed
        dojo.forEach(treeData, function(field) {
            var store = this.tree.model.store;
            store.newItem(field);
        }, this);

    },
    setOpenCallback: function(callback){
        this.tree.setOpenCallback(callback);
    },
    resetTree: function() {
        var store = this.tree.model.store;
        store.fetch( { query: { id: "*" },  
            onItem: function(item) {
                store.deleteItem(item);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I had tried replacing the code for combobox like this:

```
dojo.declare('TreeSelect',dijit.form.ComboBox,{
```

Please help me rectify it.
Thanks in advance!

Adding the code for FC_Tree:

```
dojo.declare('FC_Tree',dijit.Tree,{
    showRoot: false,
    openOnClick: true,
    noIconForNode: true,
    noMarginForNode: true,
    persist: false,
    openCallback: null,
    constructor: function(){
        if(dojo.isUndefined(arguments[0]) || dojo.isUndefined(arguments[0].model))
        {
            var forest_store = new FC_DataStore({id: 'id', label: 'label'});
            this._storeloaded = false;
            dojo.connect(forest_store,'loaded',this,function(){this._storeloaded = true;})
            this.model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({store:forest_store});
        }
    },

    setOpenCallback: function(callback){
        this.openCallback = callback;
    },

    option: {},
    itemSelected: function(item){
    },

    onClick: function(item, node, evt){
        var store = this.model.store;
        get = function(){
            return store.getValue(item, "isDir");
        };
        // on folder click mark it unselectable
        if(get("isDir")) 
        {
            this.isExpanded = true;
            this.isExpandable = true;

        }
        else
        {   //In case the item has 'onClick' delegate execute it and assign the output to 'selItem'
            var selItem = (item.onClick && item.onClick[0])? item.onClick[0](this.model.store,item.parentID[0]):item.id[0]; 

            this.option.id = item.id;
            this.option.value = item.value;
            this.option.label = item.label;
            this.itemSelected(this.option);

        }
    },

    onOpen: function(item, node){
        if(this.rootNode.item == item){
            return this.inherited(arguments);
        }

        var data = (this.openCallback != null) ? this.openCallback(item, node) : {};
        if(!data.length){
            return this.inherited(arguments);
        }
        FC_Comm.when(data,{
            onCmdSuccess: dojo.hitch(this,function(data){
                var store = this.model.store;
                var children = store.getValues(item, 'children');
                dojo.forEach(children, function(child) {
                    // don't delete child if doNotDelete flag is true
                    if(!store.getValue(child, "doNotDelete"))
                        store.deleteItem(child);
                });
                if (data) {
                    var store = this.model.store;
                    if (store) {
                        dojo.forEach(data, function(child) {
                            store.newItem(child, {parent : item, attribute: 'children'});
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    },

    refresh: function(){

        if(this._storeloaded){
            // Close the store (So that the store will do a new fetch()).
            this.model.store.clearOnClose = true;
            this.model.store.close();

            // Completely delete every node from the dijit.Tree     
            this._itemNodesMap = {};
            this.rootNode.state = "UNCHECKED";
            this.model.root.children = null;

            // Destroy the widget
            this.rootNode.destroyRecursive();

            // Recreate the model, (with the model again)
            this.model.constructor(this.model)

            // Rebuild the tree
            this.postMixInProperties();
            this._load();
            this._storeloaded = false;
        }
    },
    clear: function(){
        this.model.store.load([]);
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont get it, why use a select and not simply a textfield? maybe post a screenshot of the tree besides an opened select

Comment: I was using a tree select previously. now for a different use case i need a combobox. So I thought modifying the tree select would be best

Comment: well, ill give it a go if you would add that image - or explain the 'connectivity' between combo and tree.. Are options 1:1 with the tree children? i.e. whats this: `this.tree.option = this.option; this.addOption(this.option);`

Comment: the value that you have selected in the tree is being set to the value of the combobox.

Comment: Oh kay - problem youre facing is that the Select and ComboBox are handling their options differently. I Allways use ComboBox for scaleability - it can 'hook' onto your tree store, however with limitations

Comment: basically I am loooking for a combobox equivalent of select's `__getMenuItemForOption`

Comment: I was wondering about a similar solution and wonder if the (apparently undocumented) dojox/grid/TreeSelection widget might be part of a solution.

Comment: I was able to achieve the functionality i needed by making a widget that extended the dijit.form.textBox, dijit.form._hasdropdown and dijit.tree. I works perfectly. you just need to set the tree as this.dropdown!!

Comment: @MozenRath can you please share the code for your TreeSelect widget using TextBox, _hasDropdown and Dijit Tree. I am working on something similar and would be quite handy to get to see some code for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you will find inspiration / answer in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/QhWxz/)

The recursiveHunt and selectTreeNodeById [functions](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Tree-examples.html) are logic to seek out the path of an item by its id. Its quite excessive and you may find a better solution (dont know 100% what data your json is like)..

Basically, use FilteringSelect and reference the tree in this object. Also for Tree, reference the select.
Then for your tree, hook into load function (also called on refresh afaik) and in turn for the select, use onBlur to initate selecting treenode.

```
var combo = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    onBlur: function() {
        // called when filter-select is 'left'
        if (this.validate()) {
            // only act if the value holds an actual item reference
            var id = this.get("value");
            var name = this.get("displayedValue");
            this.tree.selectNode(id);
        }
    }
});
var tree = new dijit.Tree( {  ....
    onLoad: function() {
        combostore.setData(this.model.store._arrayOfAllItems);
    },
    onClick: function(item) {
        // uses 'this.combo', must be present
        // also, we must have the same 'base store' for both combo and model
        var _name = this.model.store.getValue(item, this.combo.searchAttr);
        this.combo.set("item", item,  false, _name);
    },
    selectNode: function(lookfor) {
        selectTreeNodeById(this, lookfor);
    },
    combo: combo // <<<<<<
});
combo.tree = tree // <<<<<<
```

Make sure that the model has a rootId, and also that your select.searchAttr matches tree.model.labelAttr. See working sample on the fiddle